# Je l'ai vu et toi [non ou pas] ?

Tags: grammaire, négation

Laquelle de ces deux phrases est correcte ?

1. Je l'ai vu et toi pas.
2. Je l'ai vu et toi non.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La plus courante des deux est la seconde, mais ça ne suffit pas. Une réponse pourrait être :

> Je l'ai vu, contrairement à toi.

De façon plus commune, on pourrait dire :

> Je l'ai vu et pas toi.

Answer (score 6):

La seconde est meilleure. Cela dit, on peut utiliser la première moyennant une légère modification :

> Je l'ai vu, mais pas toi

ou encore

> Je l'ai vu et pas toi

Construction que l'on retrouve dans une chanson connue de Jean-Jacques Goldman par exemple:

> Pourquoi je saigne
>
> Et pas toi?

La version soutenue étant

> Je l'ai vu et toi tu ne l'as pas vu.